# Labelling expression - How to combine two different functions?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, vbscript, expression

I'm not an expert of scripting and programming,
I need to use these two functions in the labelling expression in ArcGIS.

How can I combine this:

```
    Function FindLabel ( [toponimo] , [testo] )
      if (  [testo] = "PICCOLI" ) then
       FindLabel = "<CLR black='000'><ITA><FNT size = '8'>" + LCase ( [toponimo] ) + "</FNT></ITA></CLR>"
      elseif   (  [testo] = "MEDI" ) then
      FindLabel = "<CLR black='000'><ITA><FNT size = '10'>" +LCase (  [toponimo] ) + "</FNT></ITA></CLR>"
      else  
      FindLabel = "<CLR black='000'><ITA><FNT size = '12'>" + LCase ( [toponimo] ) + "</FNT></ITA></CLR>"
      end if
    End Function
```

and:

```
    Function FindLabel ([MyFieldName])
     FindLabel = PCase([MyFieldName])
    End Function
    Function PCase(strInput)
     Dim iPosition
     Dim iSpace
     Dim strOutput
     iPosition = 1
     Do While InStr(iPosition, strInput, “ “, 1) <> 0
     iSpace = InStr(iPosition, strInput, “ “, 1)
     strOutput = strOutput & UCase(Mid(strInput, iPosition, 1))
     strOutput = strOutput & LCase(Mid(strInput, iPosition + 1, iSpace - iPosition))
     iPosition = iSpace + 1
     Loop
     strOutput = strOutput & UCase(Mid(strInput, iPosition, 1))
     strOutput = strOutput & LCase(Mid(strInput, iPosition + 1))
     PCase = strO
```

The second is useful for PCase instead of LCase.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "combine"? Do you want your PCase logic to apply in addition to the logic in your first FindLabel function? Or do you need to pick one or the other depending on various if...else tests?

Comment: Yes, I need PCase logic applied to my FindLabel function (the first one)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a matter of combining your existing `FindLabel` function with the example function in the second snippet which then calls `PCase()`, so replace this:

```vbs
Function FindLabel ([MyFieldName])
    FindLabel = PCase([MyFieldName])
End Function
```

With this:

```vbs
Function FindLabel ([toponimo], [testo])
    If ([testo] = "PICCOLI") Then
        labelString = "<CLR black='0'><ITA><FNT size = '8'>" + ([toponimo]) + "</FNT></ITA></CLR>"
    ElseIf   ([testo] = "MEDI") Then
        labelString = "<CLR black='0'><ITA><FNT size = '10'>" + ([toponimo]) + "</FNT></ITA></CLR>"
    Else  
        labelString = "<CLR black='0'><ITA><FNT size = '12'>" + ([toponimo]) + "</FNT></ITA></CLR>"
    End If
    FindLabel = PCase(labelString)
End Function
```

Noting the `labelString` parameter in each `If`/`ElseIf`/`Else` which is then passed through the `FindLabel = PCase(labelString)` at the end to call your `PCase()` function, and what `PCase()` returns is sent as the result of `FindLabel()`.

Full end result for your label expression is as follows:

```vbs
Function FindLabel ([toponimo], [testo])
    If ([testo] = "PICCOLI") Then
        labelString = "<CLR black='0'><ITA><FNT size = '8'>" + ([toponimo]) + "</FNT></ITA></CLR>"
    ElseIf   ([testo] = "MEDI") Then
        labelString = "<CLR black='0'><ITA><FNT size = '10'>" + ([toponimo]) + "</FNT></ITA></CLR>"
    Else  
        labelString = "<CLR black='0'><ITA><FNT size = '12'>" + ([toponimo]) + "</FNT></ITA></CLR>"
    End If
    FindLabel = PCase(labelString)
End Function

Function PCase(strInput)
    Dim iPosition
    Dim iSpace
    Dim strOutput
    iPosition = 1
    Do While InStr(iPosition, strInput, " ", 1) <> 0
        iSpace = InStr(iPosition, strInput, " ", 1)
        strOutput = strOutput & UCase(Mid(strInput, iPosition, 1))
        strOutput = strOutput & LCase(Mid(strInput, iPosition + 1, iSpace - iPosition))
        iPosition = iSpace + 1
    Loop
    strOutput = strOutput & UCase(Mid(strInput, iPosition, 1))
    strOutput = strOutput & LCase(Mid(strInput, iPosition + 1))
    PCase = strOutput
End Function
```

I did have to fix the final parameter at the end of your script from `PCase = strO` to `PCase = strOutput` and also had to replace some unusual quote marks in the `Do While` which were causing some errors - `“ “` replaced with `" "`